# videocapture and pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, webcam, qpixmap

i use this lib http://videocapture.sourceforge.net/ for a capturing web cam. But i don't understand how it video-stream send to `qpixmap`.

Answer (score 2):

If you check out the documentation for this library, you will see its very short and sweet. http://videocapture.sourceforge.net/html/VideoCapture.html

There are two ways I can tell you that you could get your image into Qt...

**The best way - Directly into a QImage**

`getImage()` states that it will return a PIL image. PIL, if you are using the latest version, has a module called ImageQt which can take a PIL Image object and give you back a QImage. From here you could convert that to QPixmap:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from VideoCapture import Device
from PIL import Image, ImageQt

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

cam = Device()
# this is a PIL image
pilImage = cam.getImage()
# this is a QImage
qImage = ImageQt.ImageQt(pilImage)
# this is a QPixmap
qPixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(q)
```

**The other way - Write to disk first**

If you follow the example they give on this modules website, they show you how to use `saveSnapshot()` to save the image to disk. This is less desirable than the first method since you have to do disk i/o, but I will still mention it. You would then read it into your Qt app as a QPixmap:

```
cam = Device()
cam.saveSnapshot('image.jpg')

qPixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('image.jpg')
```

Do the first method. Its faster and more efficient.